# I'm getting HTTP error 404 making this code to download YouTube any idea as to why I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the links tried loads

Tags: tk-toolkit, pytube

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
from tkinter import *
from pytube import *
##just a title
root =Tk()
root.title('Youtube Downloader')


##label at the top of 
ytdLabel= Label(root,text='Enter URL of the video',font=('jost',15))
ytdLabel.pack()

##entry bar
enterURL=Entry(root,width=30)
enterURL.pack()

##
def URLDownloader():
    myvid=(str(enterURL.get()))
    video=YouTube(myvid)
    video=video.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    video.download()
   
dwnloadBtn=Button(root,text='Download',command=URLDownloader)
dwnloadBtn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Exception in Tkinter callback

```txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/jordanshodeinde/Desktop/Youtube downloader progression/youtube dowloader.py", line 25, in URLDownloader
    video=YouTube(myvid)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytube/request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: What's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your question?

Comment: my question is why am I getting this very long error and how do I resolve it to download YouTube videos

Comment: Please don't put _stories_ in the _title_. 'HTTP 404 when trying to download from YouTube' should be enough.

Comment: And yes I've tried to resolve it but the issue is I have no idea what the problem is I got another error before which was ssl certificate failed and resolved that now I'm back to a complete loss

Comment: okay, kind of hard to be concise when I have no idea what's going though lol

Comment: And **what** have you tried to resolve the problem? I would assume that any HTTP call within your scripts triggers that 404 page

Comment: using the url from the top of the browser, using the url provided when  you try to "share" ,the video removing https:// from the URL. those are the three things I've tried

Comment: also tried running the .donwload() method on its own with none of the gui code  but I get the same error so I think the main problem lies with that

Comment: Please share more details, like sample input and your debugging attempts. If you are a sole user of that package, you should report this as an issue to their bug tracker

Comment: not a sole user. as I'm new to programming so my debugging efforts have only been as follows: importing ssl , importing urllib.request importing urllib.parse trying multiple video urls , example :(https://youtu.be/36GT2zI8lVA), taking what I understood from your assumption (youtu.be/36GT2zI8lVA) and now uninstalling pytube 3  and reinstalling using this:(pip3 install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for this error has nothing to do with `Tkinter`, this is a [known bug](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/990) with the pytube package.

Not sure what version of pytube you're using but this issue always seems to be solved after a new pytube update then it goes back to the same issue sometime down the line.

But you can try `pip install pytube==10.9.2` as this is now the latest version or `python -m pip install --upgrade pytube`. Hopefully that will resolve the issue you're now facing.

Comment: Thanks for that unfortunately hasn't been solved as my pytube doesn't seem to be able to upgrade past 9.6.4 perhaps this has something to do with the m1 chip as I've tried downloading through the GitHub repository too.

Comment: No problem man... `pytube` is working fine for me though.

Comment: You were right however, checked it on an online IDE using 10.9.2 thanks very much! now I have a second issue to solve lol.

Comment: Maybe you'll have to post a new question then I guess :-)

Comment: No prob bro. :-)